# passing data from one form to another in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms Enquiry And Client ,when client is new i have to add client and then his Name must come to client name field in enquiry form combobox .
how do i do that in c#

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394889/passing-data-between-forms?rq=1 or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173973/passing-variables-into-another-form?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to add a public property to Client, and than before you show the Client form you set that property (assuming that you create a Client object from Enquiry form)... that property could also be directly connected to the combobox(get & set methods)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter to the constructor of th second form, for example:

```
public Form2(string clientName)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // ...
}
```

Then you can call it from another form:

```
{
    Form2 fm2 = new Form2("name");
    fm2.Show();
}
```